# Tcxgriddbtableview - Sum several columns in a certain row

Tags: delphi, datagrid, multiple-columns, tcxgrid, column-sum

I have a tcxgriddbtableview with multiple columns for amounts. I want to include subtotals in each row. Is it possible to define a column in such a way that it automatically totals several columns? Totalling already happens in SQL, but it should also happen dynamically when the user changes a value in a column of the table.

I'm looking for a property of the tcxgriddbtableview which takes over this function. There must be an easy way to do this, right?

Comment: so you want to show the sum of `column1` and  `column2` and `column3` in `column 4` ? I guess this can be done easily with a `calculated column` in your dataset. No need for the gridview to handle that

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I solved it now, that I called a procedure at the DataChange event, which adds the data source elements and writes this value into the data source element of column 4.